# Powershell Script Issue for finding and displaying 2 Japanese Characters instead of 1

Tags: powershell, search, rank

I wrote a script that searches through a .txt file and pulls japanese character sequences. I am trying to further optimize it and running into some trouble.

The current output looks like this [image: Output Single Sequence]

I am trying to get it to display 2 japanese character sequences instead of just the one you see above.

For example;

Instead of the single:

20. 今
21. 美

it searches and ranks for two characters:

20. 今日
21. 美人

Here is the code I am currently trying to modify

```
$folder = "/Users/mbp/Desktop/Japanese Kanji Extraction/nier_unpacked_2_extracted"
$files = gci -recurse $folder | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
$fileContents = $files | foreach { gc -encoding utf8 $_.fullname }
$lines = $fileContents | foreach { if ($_ -match "^JP: (.*)$") { $matches[1] } }
$chars = $lines | foreach { $_.ToCharArray() }
$groups = $chars | group-object
$totals = $groups | sort-object -desc -property count
```

Comment: This need more details and an example input sequence and related expected output. E.g. the each of the two characters might also be joined with another character to create a new pair. Or do they need to be consecutive? But the still, second can still be paired with the next. How are the character pairs defined?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get bi-grams from a string, you can use [a function like this](https://qiita.com/acuo/items/054278a0896e05e4477b#05-n-gram):

```
function ngram($p, $n) {
    $spr = if ($p -is "string") { "" } else { " " }
    0..([math]::max($p.length - $n, 0)) | foreach { $p[$_..($_ + $n - 1)] -join $spr } | select -u
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
...
$folder = "/path/to/text"
$files = gci -recurse $folder | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
$fileContents = $files | foreach { gc -encoding utf8 $_.fullname }
$lines = $fileContents | foreach { if ($_ -match "^JP: (.*)$") { $matches[1] } }
$bigrams = $lines | foreach { ngram $_ 2 }
$groups = $bigrams | group-object
$totals = $groups | sort-object -desc -property count
```

From [the contents in this site](https://dev.to/nyctef/extracting-game-text-from-nier-automata-1gm0), you will get the result like this:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 分が                      {分が, 分が}
    2 が良                      {が良, が良}
    2 くて                      {くて, くて}
    2 なく                      {なく, なく}
    2 気分                      {気分, 気分}
    1 関係                      {関係}
    1 ない                      {ない}
    1 い。                      {い。}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try enumeraterunes() in powershell 7.  It's easier to display in osx or the latest windows terminal.  I think the first rune is the BOM.

```
'今美' | set-content jap.txt -Encoding utf8bom
$a = cat jap.txt
$a.EnumerateRunes() | % { "$_" } 


今
美
```